# Change width, height dynamically in Jasper using parameters

Tags: jasper-reports

How can change width, height dynamically in Jasper using parameters?

```
<image onErrorType="Icon">
<reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="166" height="67" uuid="c3c0a660-62ed-4a17-8bb7-c8ed91a87b98">
    <propertyExpression name="width"><![CDATA[$P{logoWidth}]]></propertyExpression>
    <propertyExpression name="height"><![CDATA[$P{headerHeight}]]></propertyExpression>
</reportElement>
<imageExpression><![CDATA[$P{imageurl}]]></imageExpression>
```

I tried with above code block but it didn't override initial values with the parameter values.